# Use Ramda to Multiply and transform objects of an array based on a key name pattern. Return all in new flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an array of objects where each object has like duplicated 'translated' keys with the translated values for different languages, but also normal generic values like a price.

```
[
  {name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10 },
  {name_de: 'foo 2 de', name_it: 'foo 2 it', price: 20 },
  {name_de: 'foo 3 de', name_it: 'foo 3 it', price: 30 }
]
```

I need to multiply each object into the additional objects containin the values of the other languages, the key should be normalized without the language suffix to "name". Generic props like price should still exist,

Should transform into one new array like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo 1 de", 
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "foo 1 it", 
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "foo 2 de", 
        "price": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "foo 2 it", 
        "price": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "foo 3 de", 
        "price": 30
    },
    {
        "name": "foo 3 it", 
        "price": 30
    },
]
```

I am playing with R.flatten and R.groupBy but I am not getting anywhere.

Is there a smart solution?

Answer (score 1):

This will handle objects with multiple keys with two letters of date code (ie `_de`) - I've added a date property as an example.

It will convert each object to an array of pairs. Group the pairs by the language code, and then map each language code items, combine them with the generics, and convert the pairs back to objects.

```js
const { pipe, toPairs, groupBy, head, match, last, converge, omit, values, prop, adjust, replace, flip, concat, fromPairs, map } = R;

const pattern = /_([a-z]{2})$/;

const splitByCode = R.chain(pipe(
  toPairs,
  groupBy(pipe(head, match(pattern), last)), // group by the lang code
  converge((lang, gen) => 
    map(
      pipe(
        map(adjust(0, replace(pattern, ''))), // remove language code from the 1st item in each pair
        flip(concat)(gen), // combine with the generics
        fromPairs // convert to object
      ),
      lang
    ),
    [
      pipe(omit(['undefined']), values), // get all pairs with language code
      prop(['undefined']) // get all pairs without language code
    ]
  )
));

const data = [{"name_de":"foo 1 de","date_de":"date 1 de","date_it":"date 1 it","name_it":"foo 1 it","price":10},{"name_de":"foo 2 de","date_de":"date 2 de","date_it":"date 1 it","name_it":"foo 2 it","price":20},{"name_de":"foo 3 de","date_de":"date 3 de","date_it":"date 1 it","name_it":"foo 3 it","price":30}];

const result = splitByCode(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is nicely generic, in a way that's one step further than my example.  While mine would handle `name_xx` OR `date_xx` nodes, it doesn't do both at once.  One with `name_xx` and `date_xx` properties would flatten into what's probably unwanted additional nodes.  I'm impressed.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Thanks. That's a huge compliment coming from you :)

Comment: Updated my answer with a version that I believe does the same thing.  Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```js
const separateCountries = chain (x => {
  const [countries, others] = partition (test (/_[a-z]{2}$/), keys (x))
  return map (k => ({[k.slice(0, -3)]: x [k], ... pick (others, x)}), countries)
})

const prices = [{name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10 }, {name_de: 'foo 2 de', name_it: 'foo 2 it', price: 20 }, {name_de: 'foo 3 de', name_it: 'foo 3 it', price: 30 }]


console .log (separateCountries (prices))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {chain, partition, test, keys, map, pick} = R          </script>
```

This separates every key that looks like `name_ab` and retains all the properties that don't look like that on each result.  It uses `partition` to group them properly.

Here the `chain`, `test`, `keys`, and `map` calls could easily be replaced by vanilla JS features.  But the calls to `partition` and `pick` could likely only be replaced by building the same functionality into your own code.

Note that it's fairly generic, not caring about `name` for example, only that the key ends with an `_` and two letters.  The remainder of that key becomes the key in the resulting object.

### Update

Inspired by the [answer from OriDrori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58510729), I wanted a version of this which had the same behavior, so that if there are other country-level fields as well as `name`s, then they would all be grouped together into a single country object.

It's less simple than my initial answer, but still not too bad.  And it serves as an interesting alternative to that point-free implementation.

```js
const separateCountries = chain ((
  x,
  [countries, others] = partition (test (/_[a-z]{2}$/), keys (x)),
  base = pick(others, x)
) => map (
  merge(base),
  map (
    compose (mergeAll, map (k => ({[slice (0, -3, k)]: x [k]}))), 
    values (groupBy (slice (-2, Infinity), countries))
  )
))


const prices = [{"name_de":"foo 1 de", "whatit_us": "whatsit 1 us", "date_de":"date 1 de","date_it":"date 1 it","name_it":"foo 1 it","price":10},{"name_de":"foo 2 de","date_de":"date 2 de","date_it":"date 1 it","name_it":"foo 2 it","price":20},{"name_de":"foo 3 de","date_de":"date 3 de","date_it":"date 1 it","name_it":"foo 3 it","price":30}]

console .log (separateCountries (prices))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {chain, partition, test, keys, pick, map, merge, mergeAll, compose, slice, values, groupBy} = R</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Ramda here – plain modern JavaScript does the trick succinctly enough.

```js
// Split a key to its non-localized prefix and localization; return null if not localized.
// Can be customized as required.
function splitKey(key) {
  const bits = key.split("_");
  if (bits.length > 1) return bits;
  return null;
}

function generateNonlocalizedObjects(destArray, sourceObj) {
  const localizedKeys = [];
  const nonLocalizedData = {};
  Object.keys(sourceObj).forEach(key => {
    const value = sourceObj[key];
    const keyBits = splitKey(key);
    if (keyBits !== null) {
      localizedKeys.push([keyBits[0], keyBits[1], value]);
    } else {
      nonLocalizedData[key] = value;
    }
  });
  if (!localizedKeys.length) {
    // No localized data; just push the data onto the array.
    destArray.push(nonLocalizedData);
    return;
  }
  localizedKeys.forEach(([key, locale, value]) => {
    // Merge the non-localized data with the rest
    destArray.push({ ...nonLocalizedData, [key]: value, $locale: locale });
  });
}

const inputObjects = [
  { name_de: "foo 1 de", name_it: "foo 1 it", price: 10 },
  { name_de: "foo 2 de", name_it: "foo 2 it", price: 20, blep: 33 },
  { name_de: "foo 3 de", name_it: "foo 3 it", price: 30, blur: 99 },
];

const destArray = [];
inputObjects.forEach(iobj => generateNonlocalizedObjects(destArray, iobj));
console.log(destArray);
```

outputs

```
[
  { price: 10, name: 'foo 1 de', '$locale': 'de' },
  { price: 10, name: 'foo 1 it', '$locale': 'it' },
  { price: 20, blep: 33, name: 'foo 2 de', '$locale': 'de' },
  { price: 20, blep: 33, name: 'foo 2 it', '$locale': 'it' },
  { price: 30, blur: 99, name: 'foo 3 de', '$locale': 'de' },
  { price: 30, blur: 99, name: 'foo 3 it', '$locale': 'it' }
]
```

– if you don't need the `$locale` there, get rid of it. :)

Similarly, you might want to customize `splitKey()` to look more closely at the key and only split it if it ends in a "known locale" (`en`, `de`, `it`,...).

Comment: Of course you don't need Ramda; you never do, since Ramda is itself built in vanilla JS.  But the question specifically asked about Ramda (at least in tag and title.) And if you compare this to my answer, which has the same behavior, I believe, you can see that Ramda might add some value.  If nothing else, for brevity.  (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I interpreted it as OP meaning they have Ramda at their disposal :) Either way, it doesn't hurt to have a Ramda implementation and a vanilla one, I guess?

Comment: Of course.  I love how many fundamentally different answers -- and code styles -- this question has generated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not ramda, but it's not very long or complex.

```js
const input = [
  {name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10 },
  {name_de: 'foo 2 de', name_it: 'foo 2 it', price: 20 },
  {name_de: 'foo 3 de', name_it: 'foo 3 it', price: 30 }
]

const output = input.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const names = [],
          cmn = {};
    Object.keys(el).forEach(n => {
      n.startsWith("name")
      ? names.push(el[n])
      : cmn[n] = el[n];
    });    
    names.forEach(n => acc.push({name: n, ...cmn}));
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `reduce` method:

```
let sourceData =[
    {name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10 },
    {name_de: 'foo 2 de', name_it: 'foo 2 it', price: 20 },
    {name_de: 'foo 3 de', name_it: 'foo 3 it', price: 30 }
];

const result = sourceData.reduce((a,c) => {
    a.push({name: c.name_de, price: c.price});
    a.push({name: c.name_it, price: c.price});
    return a;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note that it looks as though `price` was supposed to be one of many properties not parsed, so I'm not sure this technique will expand as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you ask, however ramda is only used marginally...

```js
const languages = ['de', 'it'].map(l => `name_${l}`);

const parseLabels = (base, labels) => R.reduce(
  (res, name) => res.concat(
    R.mergeRight(base, { name }),
  ), [], labels,
);

const parseItem = R.converge(parseLabels, [
  R.pick(['price']),
  R.pipe(R.pick(languages), R.values),
]);

const parse = R.reduce(
  (res, item) => res.concat(
    parseItem(item),
  ),
  [],
);

const data = [
  {name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10 },
  {name_de: 'foo 2 de', name_it: 'foo 2 it', price: 20 },
  {name_de: 'foo 3 de', name_it: 'foo 3 it', price: 30 },
];

console.log('result', parse(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: "Marginally"?  Seven calls to six distinct functions does not seem marginal!  :-)

Comment: Note that it looks as though `price` was supposed to be one of many properties not parsed, so I'm not sure this technique will expand as needed.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that my solution also used six distinct Ramda functions, but there's no overlap with your six.

Comment: well, I wrote it in a way that scales better... (ps: "marginally" because it was mostly using api such as reduce, etc. that are also natively available)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a transducer for this:

For each object:

1. Take the values out:

```js
values({name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10})
//=> ['foo 1 de', 'foo 1 it', 10]
```

2. Separate labels and price:

```js
splitAt(-1, ['foo 1 de', 'foo 1 it', 10])
//=> [['foo 1 de', 'foo 1 it'], [10]]
```

3. Pair the price with each label:

```js
apply(xprod)([['foo 1 de', 'foo 1 it'], [10]])
//=> [['foo 1 de', 10], ['foo 1 it', 10]]
```

4. Finally pair these pairs with keys to create objects:

```js
lift(zipObj(['name', 'price']))([['foo 1 de', 10], ['foo 1 it', 10]])
//=> [{name: "foo 1 de", price: 10}, {name: "foo 1 it", price: 10}]
```

```js
const splitObjects = into([], compose(
  map(values),
  map(splitAt(-1)),
  map(apply(xprod)),
  map(lift(zipObj(['name', 'price'])))
));

console .log(flatten(splitObjects(items)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {into, compose, map, values, splitAt, apply, xprod, lift, zipObj, flatten} = R</script>
<script>
const items = [
  {name_de: 'foo 1 de', name_it: 'foo 1 it', price: 10 },
  {name_de: 'foo 2 de', name_it: 'foo 2 it', price: 20 },
  {name_de: 'foo 3 de', name_it: 'foo 3 it', price: 30 }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting.  How would you alter it if the `name_xx` properties didn't consistently come first?  How about if (as OriDrori solved for) there were other country properties, such as `date_xx` in the objects?

Comment: I made a few assumptions indeed (based on the data provided by the author): 1) all properties in the original object _can_ be processed and 2) `price` always come last. Unless the author says otherwise I wanted to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: No criticism intended; this question has been wonderful for all the different approaches presented.  I took this bit more literally perhaps than others: "but also normal generic values like a price."  I'm just curious whether you've thought how it might expand in such directions.